# How can I use the LDA for classification of dog and cat datas?

Tags: r, rstudio, lda, linear-discriminant

im pretty new in the world of R. I have a little projekt by programming with R. We have 2 Datasets, a dataset with dog datas and one with cat datas (to be clear, 80 Dog row datas and 80 cat row datas). Each of these row is a 64x64 Pixel IMG just packed in one row. I just used the PCA to classify these and plot the images of a cat and a dog. So the question now, how i can classify these 2 animals by using the linear discriminant analysis? I dont have an ideas. Maybe I can take a few looks of ur answers, so thats gonna help me a little bit to continue my progress.

I just tried the PCA on using these datsets plotting a few images of cat and dogs. Before this part, I just had to describe a grey colour palette.

Like, the first row of the cat data is give by 4.096 elements from 0-255.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a platform for programming questions. If it's Machine Learning/ Math/ Statistics, use https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You might try using the PCA scores for the linear discriminant analysis. For linear discriminant analysis you need more rows than columns but you have 160 rows and 4096 columns of data.